# Pass argment to a nested graph's startDestination

Tags: android, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I've created multiple graphs in separate files.

The first one is **GraphA** and it's includes **GraphB**. the `startDestination` of **GraphB** is **FragmentB** that has an argument named **AnID**

Now I want to pass the **AnID** from **GraphA** to **GraphB** (**FragmentB**)

Despite of the editor know about the argument but generated codes don't regard the argument:

[image]

```
    val directionB = FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToGraphB(/* HAS NOT ARGUMENT */)
    findNavController().navigate(directionB)
```

**How can I pass the argument to a nested graph?**

Answer (score 2):

I found this but it's not an official solution:

```
val direction = FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToGraphB()
findNavController().navigate(direction.actionId, FragmentBArgs(anId).toBundle())
```

**Update:**

someone introduced [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491385/2389923) by defining nested-graph arguments in action