# Android Navigation Component passing bundle as argument while using safe-args

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

If I am using sage-args an directions and they do not have possibility to pass arguments and then I do

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_authenticationFlow, bundle)
```

I am not getting this arguments in Fragment

```
 val uriString = arguments?.getString("uri")
```

Is it ok and I need to config safe args or something is done wrong with bundle passing?

UPDATE

I've changed to suggested solution but I think there is problem that I have nested login.xml graph and trying to pass this arguments to fragment in this nested graph.

**login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/loginFlow"
    app:startDestination="@id/authenticationFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authenticationFragment"
        android:name="com.softne.crm.ui.authentication.AuthenticationFragment"
        android:label="fragment_authentication"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_authentication">
        <argument
            android:name="uri"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

and here **main.xml**

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_to_authenticationFlow"
        app:destination="@id/loginFlow" >
        <argument
            android:name="uri"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </action>
```

I've modified to this code but also does not work

```
 val args: AuthenticationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    private fun handleDeepLinks() {

        val uriString = arguments?.getString("uri")
        Toast.makeText(context, uriString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

And I am using Driections class from action_to_authenticationFlow

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        val action = DashboardFragmentDirections.actionToAuthenticationFlow(uriString)
        navController.navigate(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

You navigation should look like this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.chenriquevz.pokedex.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/home_to_pokemon"
            app:destination="@+id/navigation_pokemon">
            <argument
                android:name="pokemonID"
                app:argType="string"
                app:nullable="false" />
        </action>

    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_pokemon"
        android:name="com.chenriquevz.pokedex.ui.pokemon.PokemonFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pokemon">
        <argument
            android:name="pokemonID"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
     </fragment>
```

and your destination Fragment should look like this:

```
    private val args: PokemonFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    val pokemonID= args.uri
```

And your navigation should look like this, note that the direction has its name derivated from the origin Fragment:

```
val action = HomeFragmentDirections.homeToPokemon(query)
navController.navigate(action)
```

After update your navigation graph sometimes it may require a build/clean project to generate the proper direction.

Comment: I have this but it doesn't work for me. I paste code where is may problem I think

Comment: in your example you are not using directions to navigate/pass argument, are you? Do you have the depency added to your gradle at project level?

Comment: Yes but I think this bundles should, work. In the meantime I've changed to this directions arguments but this doesn't work. I think If I have this in one xml it will work ok but in both methods, but the problem is that this login.xml is included to main.xml and I am login to nested flow. I consider whether it is possible to pass to nested flow

Comment: I tested args.uri on debugger so please do not suggest that there is old arguments.getString()

Comment: I have found two resources that may help you, as I do not have the time to replicate what you are doing.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477573/passing-arguments-to-a-nested-navigation-architecture-component-graph

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109505019   (they provide some workaround here, you will have to test it)

I just noticed that my code has args.String("whatever") and it should have been args.uri as you mentioned.

Comment: also, I just noticed that I have a code very similar to yours. Try to make it app:nullable="false"  *or*  android:defaultValue="@null"  (I think it has a high chance to help you).

Comment: It doesn't help, it do not want to pass args to nested graph startDestination from global action in parent graph, both by bundle and generated Directions/Args classes as this is URI i just set it globally on my App.INSTANCE.lastUri variable and code works, maybe in future I found better solution, I also do not want to move loginFlow back to parent graph.