# Arguments received as null while navigating to nested nav graph on Android

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Here is the code for `app_nav_graph.xml` with a nested nav graph:

```
<navigation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nested_nav_graph" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.sd.android.ui.HomeFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_nestedNavGraph"
            app:destination="@id/nested_nav_graph" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Here is `nested_nav_graph.xml`:

```
<navigation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/nestedHomeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nestedHomeFragment"
        android:name="com.sd.android.ui.NestedHomeFragment">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And here is the navigation code placed inside `HomeActivity` (hosting NavHostFragment):

```
 navController.setGraph(R.navigation.app_nav_graph);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt("key", 1);
 navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_nestedNavGraph);
```

The issue is that `NestedHomeFragment` is not receiving the passed bundle i.e. `getArguments()` is returning `null`.

Why is this happening? Any suggestions to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using? Is there a reason you're doing all this and not just [passing arguments to your start destination directly](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start)?

Comment: This is code for navigation is executed after clicking on the navigation drawer item. Navigation version is 2.3.5.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're calling all that code, including `setGraph`, as part of clicking on a navigation drawer item? Can you explain why you're doing that with something more realistic than `putInt("key", 1)` as this isn't really a pattern you should be doing at all.

Comment: But even though the pattern is correct or not (which I can try to explain and there might be better ways to achieve the navigation behaviour), the bundle should be ideally be passed to the startDestination of the nested nav graph? Is that expectation incorrect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating your `Bundle`, but you aren't actually passing it to your call to `navigate()`. You need to do that for it to actually be sent onto your destination:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 1);
navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_nestedNavGraph, bundle);
```

Comment: Oopsy! I need to sleep now. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, please [check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75159409/4516895) I posted in another thread.

Basically, it has two approaches. The first one is more reliable due to the `NavigationComponent` and `SafeArgs` scoping. The second approach is more custom via using the extra `NavDirections` class.